# Looping a multidimensional object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I have the following object in JavaScript:

```
{
  "123": {
    "room_name": "Apartment #12",
    "room_nights_nb": 1,
    "room_night_price": "110.00"
  },
  "124": {
    "room_name": "House #24",
    "room_nights_nb": 2,
    "room_night_price": "125.00"
  }
}
```

From this object I need to populate the following table:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Room name</th>
            <th>Night number</th>
            <th>Night price</th>
            <th>Total price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So, the desired output should be (between `<tbody>` and `</tbody>`):

```
<tr>
    <td>Apartment #12</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>110,00 $</td>
    <td>110,00 $</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>House #24</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>125,00</td>
    <td>250,00 $</td>
</tr>
```

So, this is what I tried:

```
for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    var object = objects[i];
    content += '<tr><td>object[room_name]</td><td>object[room_nights_nb]</td><td>object[room_night_price]</td><td>object[room_night_price] * object[room_nights_nb]</td></tr>';
}

$('table > tbody').html(content);
```

But unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Could you please help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't include `object[room_name]` *in* the string. You can either use a template literal: `\`<td>${object.room_name}</td>\`` *or* concatenate: `"<td>" + object.room_name + "</td>"`. The syntax highlighting alone should throw a red flag (*ha*) - variables/references shouldn't be highlighted the same as strings.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified the target platform, but I'd suggest on using *Object.entries()* for this:

```js
const data = {
  "123": {
    "room_name": "Apartment #12",
    "room_nights_nb": 1,
    "room_night_price": "110.00"
  },
  "124": {
    "room_name": "House #24",
    "room_nights_nb": 2,
    "room_night_price": "125.00"
  }
};

const template = ({room_name, room_nights_nb, room_night_price}) => (
`<tr><td>${room_name}</td><td>${room_nights_nb}</td><td>${room_night_price}</td></tr>`
);


const content = Object.entries(data).map(([key, val]) => template(val));

console.log(content);
```

Now you'd have an array with table rows and table cells inside it. You can loop that through and display the content however you want. Just modify the *template* function for your needs.

Comment: ... or just `Object.values(object).map(template)`, and you have to `.join()` to one string.

Comment: Hello, thank for your help. And what about the `Total price` column please?

Comment: @JonasWilms is correct, `Object.values` would work much better in here :). @popol, just add it to the template with `<td>${room_nights_nb * room_night_price}</td>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of approach,

```js
var dictionary = {
    "123": {
      "room_name": "Apartment #12",
      "room_nights_nb": 1,
      "room_night_price": "110.00"
    },
    "124": {
      "room_name": "House #24",
      "room_nights_nb": 2,
      "room_night_price": "125.00"
    }
  };

var table = document.getElementById('tbody');
Object.values(dictionary).forEach((dict) => {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    Object.values(dict).forEach((rowc) => {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.textContent = rowc;
        row.appendChild(td);
    })
    var total = dict['room_nights_nb'] * Number.parseInt(dict["room_night_price"], 10);
    var endtd = document.createElement('td');
    endtd.textContent = total;
    row.appendChild(endtd);
    table.appendChild(row);
});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Prince</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id = 'table'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                        <th>Room name</th>
                        <th>Night number</th>
                        <th>Night price</th>
                        <th>Total price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id='tbody'>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
    <script src='./index.js'></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` to and then `join()`

```js
const obj = {
  "123": {
    "room_name": "Apartment #12",
    "room_nights_nb": 1,
    "room_night_price": "110.00"
  },
  "124": {
    "room_name": "House #24",
    "room_nights_nb": 2,
    "room_night_price": "125.00"
  }
}

let res = Object.values(obj).map(a => {
  let arr = [...Object.values(a),a.room_nights_nb * a.room_night_price];
  return `<tr>${Object.values(a).map(x => `<td>${x}</td>`).join('')}</tr>`

})
console.log(res)
document.querySelector('table tbody').innerHTML = res.join('')
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Room name</th>
            <th>Night number</th>
            <th>Night price</th>
            <th>Total price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

objects.length is undefined, because it's an object, not an array. However you can loop  you object's properties like this:

```
var content = "";

for(var i in objects) {
    var currentObject = objects[i];
    var currentRow    = [
        currentObject[room_name],
        currentObject[room_nights_nb],
        currentObject[room_night_price],
        currentObject[room_night_price] * currentObject[room_nights_nb]
    ];

    content += "<tr><td>" + currentRow.join("</td><td>") + "</td></tr>";
}

$("table > tbody").html(content);
```